# C-W Multiplier Unipolar Input

Tags: voltage, multiplier

[image: Driver Circuit]

I was seeing some circuits for a Cockroft-Walton multiplier.Most of them seem to be using an AC input voltage.My specific query is ,would this multiplier work with a uni-polar (pulsed DC) input. For example a square wave from 0~100V for example.
TIA

Comment: An interesting application of this idea: DEC R-series logic (as used in the original PDP-8) uses the change between its -3v and 0v logic levels along with a single stage multiplier to generate a +3v signal that is used to activate edge-triggered latches, producing a much simpler equivalent to the standard D-type flip flop we use in most sequential logic circuits today.  See description [here](https://hackaday.io/project/8449-hackaday-ttlers/log/130460-bizarre-dtl-logic-levels-the-discrete-component-pdp-8).

Answer (score 1):

It should work perfectly, just be sure that the first capacitor can discharge when the output is 0, a push pull configuration can be useful for your application

Edit: added a schematic for you

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQm2kE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also sorry it looks this way, but circuit lab doesn't allow for diagonal components

Comment: Thanks for replying,but could not quite grasp that.Any link or a diagram,if your time permits ?

Comment: You first! Show us where your pulsed DC is coming from.

Comment: Yes,I should have shown the circuit before. I have attached an image file,hope it is view-able.

Comment: the schematic you show should work proerly